SQLite Query does not return data when "T" is included in datetimes in the WHERE clause
The following query doesn't return any data:
SELECT "t0"."id" AS "res0", "t0"."time" AS "res1", "t1"."name" AS "res2", "t1"."description" AS "res3", "t1"."type" AS "res4"
FROM "menus" AS "t0"
INNER JOIN "meals" AS "t1"
INNER JOIN "meal_for_menus" AS "t2"
ON (("t2"."menu__id")=("t0"."id")) AND (("t2"."meal__name")=("t1"."name"))
WHERE ("t0"."time") BETWEEN ('2024-08-11T00:00:00') AND ('2024-08-11T23:59:00');

but the following query does return data:
SELECT "t0"."id" AS "res0", "t0"."time" AS "res1", "t1"."name" AS "res2", "t1"."description" AS "res3", "t1"."type" AS "res4"
FROM "menus" AS "t0"
INNER JOIN "meals" AS "t1"
INNER JOIN "meal_for_menus" AS "t2"
ON (("t2"."menu__id")=("t0"."id")) AND (("t2"."meal__name")=("t1"."name"))
WHERE ("t0"."time") BETWEEN ('2024-08-11 00:00:00') AND ('2024-08-11 23:59:00');

The difference is the "T" in the datetimes from the first query. I see "T" is supported by SQLite  so I don't understand why the first query doesn't work.
FWIW, this query was generated by beam-sqlite.
I'll try to execute a raw query but I wish I could keep the query generated by beam:
todaysMenu :: Connection -> Day -> IO [(Menu, Meal)]
todaysMenu conn day =
  runBeamSqliteDebug putStrLn conn $
    runSelectReturningList $
      select $
        manyToMany_
          (_pacomerMealForMenus paComerDb)
          _mealformenuMenu
          _mealformenuMeal
          ( filter_
              ( \menu ->
                  between_
                    (_menuTime menu)
                    (val_ $ LocalTime day (TimeOfDay 0 0 0))
                    (val_ $ LocalTime day (TimeOfDay 23 59 0))
              )
              (all_ (_pacomerMenus paComerDb))
          )
          (all_ (_pacomerMeals paComerDb))


Thanks in advance for any explanation about the issue.

"SQLite does not have a dedicated date/time datatype. Instead, date and time values can stored as... a text string that is an ISO 8601 date/time value". (Quoted from the top of the docs page you linked to.) I suspect your BETWEEN is doing string comparison, not datetime comparison. You will probably need to get clever with normalizing to strings for which BETWEEN does the right thing or using functions like timediff to implement something BETWEEN-like by hand.
